# git very slow to open connection with github... after desplaying error message "fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered. A task was canceled."

Tags: git, github, fork

I have a weird problem with git / fork accessing github from one PC (BadPC) while others are just fine.

It started with "fork" taking ages doing anything on BadPC regardless of my repo from github.

I eventually managed to reproduce my problem from the git command by adding the following entry in gitconfig

```
[credential]
  helper = manager
```

Then, whatever my git command, I wait for about 20 seconds, then get the error msg "*fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered. A task was canceled*." but then the command succeeds.

I tried using a Personal Access Token but then again I wait 20 seconds before it finally works.

Comparing to my other PCs, I can see that the working ones have one entry in "Credential Manager" for

*git:https://github.com* and the user name is "Personal Access Token" while on the bad PC, I get several entries for

- git:https://github.com
- git:https://MyGitHubUser@github.com
- git:https://MyGitHubUser@github.com/

and all three entries have my actual user name instead of "Personal Access Token"

Of course, I tried deleting the entries but they come back like this each time.

Finally, if I remove the [credential] entry in gitconfig, then the git command line works fine again.
It would also appear that Visual Studio git integration works fine in that case.

But fork carries on being a pain.
Note that I cannot see any error message in fork. It's just VERY slow doing anything.

Any idea?

Thanks

PS: I use Windows 10 on all machines and various version of git (2.9.2.windows.1 and 2.20.1.windows.1 on "good" PCs and 2.26.2.windows.1 on Bad PC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% certain but I think I finally got rid of the problem as follows

- close fork
- open windows credential manager
- delete entries for git:https://... AS WELL AS Paddle-Fork-??????
- open fork
- fetch, which prompts for github login/password

ET VOILA!!!

For some unknown reason, it seems to have done the trick (I had not thought about deleting the entry Paddle-Fork-??? before)

Hope it helps someone...